# Spring Data Neo4j Repository for Relationship Entity

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I wish to query the RelationshipEntity like we query the NodeEntity.

Package Info:

```
groupId=org.springframework.data
artifactId=spring-data-neo4j
version=5.1.5.RELEASE
```

I have posted the dummy code below. Please don't mind if there are any mistakes or errors as long as the concept is clear.

---

---

NodeEntity (1) -> Employee

```
@NodeEntity("Employee")
public class Employee{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    String name;

    // Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Relationship(type = STARTED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> starts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = PAUSED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> pause = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = STOPED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> stops = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = COMPLETED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> action = new ArrayList<>();

    // Default Relationship
    @Relationship(type = ACTION, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> action = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

---

NodeEntity (2) -> Project

```
@NodeEntity("Project")
public class Project{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    String name;

    // Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

RelationshipEntity -> Status

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class Status {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    String name;

    // Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @StartNode
    private Employee employee;

    @EndNode
    private Project project;
}
```

---

This Repository works perfectly fine

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
    Employee findByName(String name);

    @Query("MATCH (e:Employee)-[r]->(p:Project) WHERE e.name={empName} AND p.name={prjName} RETURN e ")
    Employee getEmployeeWorkingOnProjectId(@Param("empName") String empName, @Param("prjName") String prjName);
}
```

---

This Repository does not works.
**getEmployeeWorkingOnProject(String,String)** returns **NULL**

> I have made modifications after `RETURN` keyword, for example modifying it from `RETURN *` to the alias like `RETURN e,r,p` and also tried changing the sequence of the alias in the return as well.

> I wish to get all the status (edges) associated with the specific employee and the specific project.

```
public interface StatusRepository extends CrudRepository<Status, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (e:Employee)-[r]->(p:Project) WHERE e.name={empName} AND p.name={prjName} RETURN * ")
    Status getEmployeeWorkingOnProject(@Param("empName") String empName, @Param("prjName") String prjName);


    /* OR 
    @Query("MATCH (e:Employee)-[r]->(p:Project) WHERE e.name={empName} AND p.name={prjName} AND r.name={statusName} RETURN * ")
    Status getEmployeeWorkingOnProject(@Param("empName") String empName, @Param("prjName") String prjName, @Param("statusName") String statusName)
    */
}
```

**CYPHER Result in Neo4j Browser**:

(Replaced the real project image with test image)

### [image]

#### Desired Outcomes (For example)

```
{
  Status: {
    name: ..,
    Employee: {
      ...
    },
    Project: {
      ...
    }
  }
},
{
  Status: {
    name: ..,
    Employee: {
      ...
    },
    Project: {
      ...
    }
  }
},
..
```

OR

```
STARTED : {
  Employee: {
    ...
  },
  Project: {
    ...
  }
},
STOPPED : {
  Employee: {
    ...
  },
  Project: {
    ...
  }
},
```

OR other kind of similar results where the Relationship entity holds both the connecting nodes.

Comment: Can your query get the correct results in the neo4j browser?

Comment: I have added the result

Comment: Why are you matching Employee on the StatusRepository?

Comment: Because I want to get specific employee's status not the status of everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make `StatusRepository` to work after removing the specific code from `Employee` (Model/Entity) mentioned below:

```
    @Relationship(type = STARTED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> starts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = PAUSED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> pause = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = STOPED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> stops = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = COMPLETED, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> action = new ArrayList<>();

    // Default Relationship
    @Relationship(type = ACTION, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Status> action = new ArrayList<>();
```